# Download Azure Blob image to memorystream in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, azure-blob-storage

The code below will copy an image file from Azure blob storage, and create a new image file locally. This local image will then be added to a List for further databinding to the XAML UI.

```
        string accountName = "testacc";
        string accountKey = "123abc";
        string container = "textcontainer";

        List<Mydata> items = new List<Mydata>();
        BitmapImage bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage();

        StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
        CloudBlobClient cli = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer = cli.GetContainerReference(container);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("xbox.jpg");

        // Here I need to copy the data stream directely to the BitmapImage instead of creating a file first
        StorageFile photoFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp_image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await blob.DownloadToFileAsync(photoFile);
        bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photoFile.Path));

        items.Add(new Mydata() { image = bitmapToShow });

        DataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

The code below will copy an image file from Azure blob storage, and create a new image file locally. This local image will then be added to a List for further databinding to the XAML UI.

Hovewer - in order to get more efficient, I am looking for a way to avoid creating the image file locally first. I am looking for a way where the image file in the Azure blob storage are copied to a MemoryStream and then passed directely into a BitmapImage.

I have not fiugred out to code that myself, and the code snippets I have not found, do not work for Windows Phone 8.1. I am programming in C# for Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App (not Silverlight).

Can someone help me with the code needed to get that functionality?

Comment: Did you try CloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync?

Comment: Hi Mike. Yes - but I must admit, that I did not use it correctly. I don't really understand how to build up the code using it. If you have a working code example or a link, that would be of great help. Then I could try to incorporate it into my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this Works. It might not be perfect, but it Works. Comments or corrections are welcome.

```
    string accountName = "testacc";
    string accountKey = "123abc";
    string container = "textcontainer";

    List<Mydata> items = new List<Mydata>();
    BitmapImage bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage();
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream memstream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
    CloudBlobClient cli = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer = cli.GetContainerReference(container);
    CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("xbox.jpg");

    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memstream.CloneStream());
    bitmapToShow.SetSource(memstream);

    items.Add(new Mydata() { image = bitmapToShow });

    DataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
Stream photoStream = await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(photoFile)
bitmapToShow = new BitmapImage(photoStream);
```

Hope it helps,

Drew

Comment: Hi Drew - no it does not work. The thing is that the variable 'photoFile' is actually the file I want to avoid to create. However - I just found the solution a few minutes ago, inspired by your code snippet. I will update the post in a minute. Many thanks!